# Typescript vscode doesn't show an error when property is not defined because of extending from mixin

Tags: typescript, visual-studio-code

Using base class mixin in Typescript to ease work with subscriptions in Angular.

Unfortunatelly when extending from base class mixin vscode loses the ability of code analysis to notify me when any class property is not defined.

Instead, it shows the property as type `any`.

Any solution?

Here is the [Stackblitz demo](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-4cotg7?file=src/app/app.component.ts)

Comment: While a link to Stackblitz is useful to demonstrate the full problem, it may be interesting to paste the relevant code directly in the question, in order to make it self-contained, and easy to read, for future readers.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Instead of declaring the constructor function like this:

```
export type Constructor<T> = new (...args: any[]) => T;
```

Declare it like this:

```
export type Constructor = new (...args: any[]) => {};
```

The empty type `{}` expresses an object that doesn't have any property, which makes it extendable by any object, and this is precisely what you need in `SubscriptionHandler<T extends Constructor>(Base: T)`.

That allows the actual return type of the constructor function to be taken in account in `SubscriptionHandler` instead of `any` like you currently have when you write `SubscriptionHandler<T extends Constructor<any>>(Base: T)`.

I've forked your Stackblitz [here](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-fuq9hg?file=src/app/app.component.ts).

Comment: Sir you are a genius!